# How i will update the available data with new data and show on available textField

Tags: java

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
             String s2= jTextField3.getText();
             String s1=jTextField4.getText();
             int a=Integer.parseInt(s1);
             int b=Integer.parseInt(s2);
             int c=a+b;
             String result=String.valueOf(c);


    String query;
    query ="UPDATE `stock` SET `pname`='"+jTextField2.getText()+"',`available`="+jTextField3.setText(result)+",`mrp`="+jTextField5.getText()+" WHERE `id`="+jTextField1.getText();
executeSQlQuery(query,"Update");   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. You must specify condition after where. You haven't specified any id so that it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you specify the "where" condition.

Use a `PreparedStatment` to create the SQL. It is easier to structure the query and it will do the SQL formatting for you:

Basic example to get you started:

```
String sql = "UPDATE Page SET Title = ? WHERE Name = ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt.setString( 1, textField1.getText() ); // variable for the title
stmt.setString( 2, textField2.getText() ); // variable for the where condition
stmt.executeUpdate();
stmt.close();
```